# Tap to draw Polylines and Polygons Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I made a few buttons so that I could draw polylines and polygons by tapping on the map. I have no idea how to do it. Thanks for the help.

tapping two or more places on the map and uniting them with polylines or closing them with polygons

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import Floaty

class CroquiViewController: UIViewController, FloatyDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var floaty = Floaty()
var flag = Int()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    layoutFAB()
}
func layoutFAB() {
    let item = FloatyItem()
    item.hasShadow = false

    floaty.hasShadow = false
    floaty.buttonColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2558874488, green: 0.5951498747, blue: 0.8528174758, alpha: 1)
    floaty.plusColor = UIColor.white
    floaty.itemButtonColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2558874488, green: 0.5951498747, blue: 0.8528174758, alpha: 1)
    floaty.addItem("Ponto", icon: UIImage(named: "icons8-marker")){ item in
        self.flag = 1
    }
    floaty.addItem("Linhas", icon: UIImage(named: "icons8-polyline")){ item in
        self.flag = 2
    }
    floaty.addItem("Polígonos", icon: UIImage(named: "icons8-polygone")) { item in
        self.flag = 3
    }
    floaty.paddingX = self.view.frame.width/2 - floaty.frame.width/0.32
    floaty.fabDelegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(floaty)

}


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    if self.flag == 1{
    print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
    //mapView.clear() // clearing Pin before adding new
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    marker.map = mapView
    }else if self.flag == 2{
     print(flag)
    }else if self.flag == 3{
        print(flag)
    }
}}
```

Comment: hi maybe this question could be your reference [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679742/how-make-polygon-without-intersection-in-swift/50725881#50725881](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679742/how-make-polygon-without-intersection-in-swift/50725881#50725881)

Answer (score 0):

These functions can help you.

mapView() -> insert the tapped coordinates into array and create marker there

createMarker() - > create the marker on that coordinate

createPolygon() - > create the polygon using that array (call this function on any button tap you want)

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
var polygonPath = GMSPolyline();

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
    let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)

    coordinates.append(destination)
    createMarker(point: coordinate)
}

func createMarker(point: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point.latitude, longitude: point.longitude)
    marker.map = mapView
}

func createPolygon(){

    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    for coordinate in coordinates{
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude))
    }
    path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinates[0].latitude, longitude: coordinates[0].longitude))

    polygonPath = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polygonPath.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    polygonPath.strokeWidth = 2.0
    polygonPath.map = mapView
}
```